# Persisting Data in an Android View

Tags: android, view, broadcast

I have a view class that gets instantiated many times, with each instance listening to a different broadcast message.  Since views can get destroyed or worse yet, recycled, I need a way to persist a value for the view somehow (the Broadcast message that I am supposed to listen to).  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best (or standard) way to do this is by the [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. I don't know what kind of data do you need to persist, that could be conditional in some cases.